# console object in jade view

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

```
tbody
  -var i = 0;           
    each data in myData
      -i = counter + 1;
      tr
        td #{i}
        td #{data.date}
```

Above is my jade, how can I `console.log(myData)` to see how's the structure look like? I don't want to go back to controller / model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lines starting with `-` are executed as Javascript:

```
- console.log(mydata)
```

Like:

```
tbody
  -var i = 0;       
  - console.log(mydata)    
    each data in myData
      -i = counter + 1;
      tr
        td #{i}
        td #{data.date}
```

Comment: Does the space before `console` matter?

Comment: No, I just put it for clarity

Answer (score 1):

Since jade templates eventually get compiled to javascript, you can just use console.log.

```
tbody
  - var i = 0;       
  - console.log('data =>', myData)    
  each data in myData
    -i = i + 1;
    tr
      td #{i}
      td #{data.date}
```

However if you are precompiling on server and want the console message be printed each time a rendered template is inserted in the DOM, you can inject a script block:

```
tbody
  -var i = 0;       
  script console.log('data =>', !{JSON.stringify(myData)})    
  each data in myData
    -i = i + 1;
    tr
      td #{i}
      td #{data.date}
```

Comment: Careful, text after the tag is escaped, so if you do `script console.log(1&&2)` it will not work.